# Does Aria2 continue to seed afrer closing the terminal where i called it?

Tags: command-line, aria2

If I call `aria2c "magnet:url"`, and after the download completes and I have seeded for long enough I feel I have contributed my fair-share, I close the terminal, will it continue to seed in the background?